# Getting Scopes and Clients from Database instead of InMemoryClients & InMemoryScopes Identity Server 3

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I want to read Scopes and Clients from database instead of InMemoryClients & InMemoryScopes in Identity Server 3.

Any one please help me how to read how we can achieve this in identity server 3.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ef/overview.html):

If scope or client data is desired to be loaded from a database (rather than use in-memory configuration), then we provide a Entity Framework based implementations of the IClientStore and IScopeStore services.

If you do not wish to use Entity Framework, you just need to implement these two interfaces yourself.

Comment: Hi Brock thanks for your response.As per your Answer I have follow the below mentioned example to create IClientStore,IScopeStore interface and tables for scopes,clients in database https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework . Now I am again stuck that how I can enter the data for Clients and Scopes in database. Could you please provide me any example or link which contains database with data for Clients & Scopes

Comment: This tool might help: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Cli