# Get Clients and Scopes from database in identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to read Scopes and Clients from database instead of InMemoryClients & InMemoryScopes in Identity Server 4. i read [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738096/getting-scopes-and-clients-from-database-instead-of-inmemoryclients-inmemorysc), but its about identity version3 and i cant find `IScopeStore` and `IClientStore` interface which exist in v3. how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IClientStore` still exists, within the `IdentitServer4.Stores` namespace.

I haven't used `IScopeStore`, but with the changes talked about in Dominicks blog (https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/01/new-in-identityserver4-resource-based-configuration/) I suspect that it has been replaced with `IResourceStore` (same namespace).